# Trying to migrate a mysql server to AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mysqldump, amazon-rds

Please advise on how to migrate my local mysql server to the cloud.

Currently I have a Fedora linux box and a NAS attached to it via ethernet.
I believe the best way to go about it is :

1. Take a mysqldump of all databases
2. Create an amazon RDS instance and try to load from the created mysqldump
3. Shift local connection to this instance

Am I on the right track ?
How should I go about doing (1). I have a username and password based access to the mysql server and it has only 1 database. I tried to follow a few links on the net but the commands did not seem to work.

Is (2) even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Even that this is old question just wanted to inform that (1) & (2) are possiable:

```
sudo mysqldump --databases world --single-transaction --compress --order-by-primary –u <local_user> -p<local_password> | mysql --host hostname –-port 3306 –u <RDS_user_name> –p<RDS_password>
```

also see:
[AWS - importing Data from a MySQL DB to an Amazon RDS MySQL DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html)